# avoid delete space while wrong typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a code in JQuery to validate a name with format letters and spaces only. The problem is, when I type a wrong format next to space, the space disappeared and the cursor is next to last letter. This is my code:

```
<script>
 $('input[name="name"]').on('keyup', function(e) {
  var re = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/.test(this.value);
  if(!re) {
   this.value = this.value.replace(/[0-9\W]+$/, '');
   $('#err_name').show();
  } else {
  $('#err_name').hide();
  }
 })
</script>
```

Comment: My guess is that `\W` matches the space. You should instead negate the pattern you used in the test.

Comment: Try `.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/g, '')`

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this line

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/[0-9\W]+$/, '');
```

to this line

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/[0-9]+$/, '');
```

Because if you will use \w it replace space also.

Comment: Where is the explanation as to why?